# How do I scale a 2D matrix representing the values of a function in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, math, matrix, scaling

I have a 2D matrix in MATLAB (say M1) that represents the values of some mathematical function f(x,y). I want to scale this function by a factor s, where s is an integer. That is, I want a matrix (say M2) containing the values of the function f(x/s, y/s). How do I do it? I don't quite understand the relation between the number of rows of my original matrix and the new matrix. Here is what my attempt so far is:

```
originalMatrix = magic(10);
s = 2; %scaling factor

% Get the size of the original matrix
[rows, cols] = size(originalMatrix);

% Create a grid of coordinates corresponding to the original matrix
[x, y] = meshgrid(1:cols, 1:rows);

% Scale the coordinates
scaledX = x / s;
scaledY = y / s;

% Create a grid of coordinates for the scaled matrix
[scaledCols, scaledRows] = size(originalMatrix);
scaledCols=scaledCols*m;
scaledRows=scaledRows*m;
[scaledXGrid, scaledYGrid] = meshgrid(1:scaledCols, 1:scaledRows);
```

I think I have created the new grids correctly but I can't figure out how to proceed.

Caveat: I do not need interpolation - I am perfectly fine with having values between the new coordinates be 0. I recognize that if my scaling is smaller then information will be lost - I am fine with that but I don't understand how to go about it. If I end up needing interpolation, what method do I use? Does MATLAB have some scaling method?

Comment: Have you tried `scaledMatrix=originalMatrix./s` ?

Comment: @XZhang that scales the values of the matrix, not the coordinates. I want to scale the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to index in to the original matrix with some skipping or duplication then, e.g.

```
originalMat=magic(10);
s=2;
scaledMat=originalMat(1:s:end,1:s:end);
scaleupMat=scaledMat(reshape(repmat(1:5,s,1),1,[]),reshape(repmat(1:5,s,1),1,[]));
```

> originalMat =
>
> ```
> 92    99     1     8    15    67    74    51    58    40
> 98    80     7    14    16    73    55    57    64    41
>  4    81    88    20    22    54    56    63    70    47
> 85    87    19    21     3    60    62    69    71    28
> 86    93    25     2     9    61    68    75    52    34
> 17    24    76    83    90    42    49    26    33    65
> 23     5    82    89    91    48    30    32    39    66
> 79     6    13    95    97    29    31    38    45    72
> 10    12    94    96    78    35    37    44    46    53
> 11    18   100    77    84    36    43    50    27    59
> ```

> scaledMat =
>
> ```
> 92     1    15    74    58
>  4    88    22    56    70
> 86    25     9    68    52
> 23    82    91    30    39
> 10    94    78    37    46
> ```
>
> scaleupMat =
>
> ```
> 92    92     1     1    15    15    74    74    58    58
> 92    92     1     1    15    15    74    74    58    58
>  4     4    88    88    22    22    56    56    70    70
>  4     4    88    88    22    22    56    56    70    70
> 86    86    25    25     9     9    68    68    52    52
> 86    86    25    25     9     9    68    68    52    52
> 23    23    82    82    91    91    30    30    39    39
> 23    23    82    82    91    91    30    30    39    39
> 10    10    94    94    78    78    37    37    46    46
> 10    10    94    94    78    78    37    37    46    46
> ```

It's also possible to upscale with zero fills by indexing

```
upzeroMat=zeros(s.*size(scaledMat));
upzeroMat(1:s:end,1:s:end)=scaledMat;
```

> upzeroMat =
>
> ```
> 92     0     1     0    15     0    74     0    58     0
>  0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
>  4     0    88     0    22     0    56     0    70     0
>  0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
> 86     0    25     0     9     0    68     0    52     0
>  0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
> 23     0    82     0    91     0    30     0    39     0
>  0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
> 10     0    94     0    78     0    37     0    46     0
>  0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
> ```

Comment: This is almost what I want - expect, is there a way to make the upscaled matrix a matrix of 0s, with only the scaled coordinates having non-zero (and the original) values?

Comment: @requiemman I updated the answer to add this possibility, still there are many other ways to achieve the same effect.